# How can I retrieve the contents a multi page editor plugin when selecting "Run as" in Eclipse Plugin Development?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

An eclipse plugin is needed to allow users to input a script and run that script through the IDE. For this I've implemented an eclipse plugin, using the multi-page editor template. I added the extension `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts` and provided a reference to my implementation of the interface `org.eclipse.debug.ui.ILaunchShortcut`. This interface requires to provide an implementation of these methods:

```
public void launch(final ISelection selection, final String mode);
public void launch(final IEditorPart editor, final String mode);
```

When the user - e.g. me - right clicks the file from the project explorer, selects "run as" and selects the launcher I provided, then the implementation of this launch method is hit. The first method - i.e. the `ISelection` version - is hit when selecting the file from the project explorer. The second method - i.e. the `IEditorPart` version - is hit when right clicking the editor zone and selecting the launcher through the "run as" option from the context menu.

I now need to find out how I can retrieve the contents of that editor page. In the first method I believe I could retrieve the filename with the below code:

```
IFile file = (IFile) ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
String path = file.getFullPath().makeAbsolute().toString();
```

However, the that path is relevant with respect to the root of the project. I don't know how to retrieve the path of the root of the project.

The implementation of the second method is more problematic given I don't know how to find the path based on the `IEditorPart`.

I hope you can help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get the file that the editor is current editing you can use something like:

```java
IPath filepath = null;

IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

IFile file = input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
if (file != null) {
   filepath = file.getFullPath();
}

if (filepath == null) {
    ILocationProvider locationProvider = input.getAdapter(ILocationProvider.class);
    if (locationProvider != null) {
        filepath = locationProvider.getPath(input);
    }
}
```

which tries to get the `IFile` frpm the editor directly and if that fails tries for a location provider.